# How to make items automatically inherit padding from container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button like so:

[image]

On hover:

[image]

So far it has worked in Desktop with the following code:

```
.white-button-arrow {
    width: 70%;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 3px #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.white-button-arrow-text {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: Friends-UltraBold !important;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.white-button-arrow-icon {
    font-size: 200%;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff29;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 22px 20px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transform-origin: right;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover .white-button-arrow-icon {
    color: #ff5a45;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-indent: -60%;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover {
    background: #ff5a45;
}
```

```
<div>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener"> 
        <button class="white-button-arrow" style="width: 100%; translate: 0px 200px;"> 
            <span class="white-button-arrow-text"><b>GOOGLE-MAPS</b></span> 
            <span class="white-button-arrow-icon" style="font-family:"> > </span>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, it is not a great solution, since I was still manually putting in the padding.
When I tried scale it down to use it for the mobile version, it become like so:

[image]

Then I realize that it may not work properly since there are so many different screen sizes, which leads to the question: Is there a way for the arrow part's black box on the right to automatically fill whatever size the container is?

Comment: You can't put a `button` inside a link, it's invalid HTML. Use a link OR a button, They do different things. Here, it seems you don't need a `button` at all as you are taking the reader to a new page.

Comment: First of all: `button` and `a` are both considered "interactive" elements, and as such _must not_ be nested into each other.

Comment: targeting the issue itself, you are using a wrong approach. You want the `height` of that element to be `100%` relative to its container and you need it to center its content vertically instead of using `padding`

Comment: Yes, I have also heard that ```button``` cannot be wrapped inside ```a```, however using ```a``` alone just mess up the style for some reason, so I ended up with this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using padding to center the text content of the `.white-button-arrow-icon` you may just set its `height: 100%` so that it will fill the space inside its container.

Here I slightly simplified the scenario removing unneeded stylings and added a `div` container wrapping the `>` text inside.

```css
.white-button-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 75px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.white-button-arrow-text {
  padding-left: .5em;
  font-family: Friends-UltraBold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.white-button-arrow-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover .white-button-arrow-icon {
  color: #ff5a45;
  padding-left: 10%;
  text-indent: -60%;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover {
  background: #ff5a45;
}
```

```html
<button class="white-button-arrow"> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-text">
    <b>GOOGLE-MAPS</b>
  </span> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-icon">
    <span>&gt;</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

And since you showed twice in your pitures an arrow looking like an actual arrow instead of being `>` that I changed as `&gt;` in my example above, here I show how you might use a fontawesome `arrow-right`.

```css
.white-button-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70%;
  height: 75px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
    
  padding: 0;  
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.white-button-arrow-text {
  padding-left: .5em;
  font-family: Friends-UltraBold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.white-button-arrow-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;  
}

.white-button-arrow:hover .white-button-arrow-icon {
  color: #ff5a45;
  padding-left: 10%;
  text-indent: -60%;
}

.white-button-arrow:hover {
  background: #ff5a45;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<button class="white-button-arrow"> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-text">
    <b>GOOGLE-MAPS</b>
  </span> 
  <span class="white-button-arrow-icon">      
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>      
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I used ">" in the question because the arrows in the images are custom font already, so I didn't want to confuse everyone with the code.

Comment: and was the question correctly addressed? the arrow addition was just for filling time but you didn't say anything if the solution correctly addressed the issue you asked for. If it did just feel free to accept the answer; if not, just tell your concerns here in the comments

Comment: I am trying to figure out right now, the first thing is that my web builder is not allowing the second div inside the button, so the div ```<div class="white-button-arrow-icon">```
is just being pushed outside for some reason.

Comment: Also using your css is doin the same effect to the buttons in the desktop version where the black part is just going out of the container as well, but I reckon it has something to do with the problem I said in the comment above.

Comment: for sure I I underestimated one fact.. `button` should contain phrasal content only so `div` are not valid .. but `span` are. So I corrected my snippets. Further than that I don't know how to help you

Comment: I have tried to fix it, but ```height: 100%``` would still make the black part higher than the container for some reason, so for now I have resorted to using a fixed height for both the button and the black box, hopefully someone else can help me, thank you!

Comment: did you make sure you adopted the same exact style like I did in my demo? I ask because it's strange.. I removed some transforms and also the `position: relative`. By the way I apologize I downvoted the question but it doesn't allow me to restore the original value unfortunately. I didn't correctly get the first comment you replied before and assumed the issue persisted for the wrong reason

Comment: Yeah I copied the exact same code, it is still the same with the image in my question. About the downvote, don't think too much about it.

Comment: ok then try to inspect the element inside your browser after opening your page. For example if using both Chrome or Firefox you may inspect the `<button>` and in partcular paying attention to the `.white-button-arrow-icon` span. Make sure there are no css rule colliding on the same element. Because if you have both my css rules and the previous ones, some attributes may interfere where one wins. Is the padding set as `0 .5em`? That detail alone might be why you see the black background overflowing the container in case the `padding-top` or `-bottom` are `> 0`